# Replacing parameters based on outcomes

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, kql

in the below script we are checking avg availability of URL status in the selected time range and also latest health status for last 3 minutes all works good but as you know log analytics data injection is slow few times because of that when checking last 3 minutes for latest health status we are getting null values so it will show as unhealthy but avg will show as healthy because user selected timerange of last 4 hours then there will be records with all healthy status.

```
let start = {TimeRange:start};
let grain =  {TimeRange:grain};
workspace(name).login_CL
| extend healthy=iff(StatusCode_s == 'OK' , 100 , 0)
| where TimeGenerated>={TimeRange:end}-3m and TimeGenerated<={TimeRange:end}
| summarize Availability=avg(healthy) by EnvName_s, ClientName_s
| extend HealthStatus=0.000
| extend LatestHealthStatus=Availability
| project Client=ClientName_s,Environment=EnvName_s,HealthStatusAverage = HealthStatus,LatestHealthStatus
)
| union
workspace(name).login_CL
| extend healthy=iff(StatusCode_s == 'OK' , 100 , 0)
| where TimeGenerated>={TimeRange:start} and TimeGenerated<={TimeRange:end}
| summarize pageAvailability=avg(healthy) by EnvName_s, ClientName_s
| extend LatestHealthStatus=0.000
| extend HealthStatus=pageAvailability
| join
(  workspace(name).login_CL
| extend healthy=iff(StatusCode_s == 'OK' , 100 , 0)
| where TimeGenerated>={TimeRange:start} and TimeGenerated<={TimeRange:end}
| make-series lifeline = avg(healthy) on TimeGenerated from start to now() step grain by EnvName_s, ClientName_s
) 
on EnvName_s
| project  Environment=EnvName_s,HealthStatusAverage = HealthStatus,LatestHealthStatus,Lifeline=lifeline
| summarize AverageHealth=sum(HealthStatusAverage), 
  LatestHealth=sum(LatestHealthStatus),HearthbeatAvg=make_list(Lifeline) by 
  Environment
```

what we need is if latesthealth is unhealthy because of any reason average also need to show as unhealthy i have attached screenshot of workbook  for reference

Comment: Can you please clarify your question by providing sample data using datatable() operator, and also specify what expected output would look like?

Comment: you also say there's a screenshot but there isn't :)